# Is it possible to add a logo or other picture in an Excel sheet and lock its position on the sheet?

Tags: excel

I am looking for a way to add a logo or other picture in an Excel sheet and lock its position on the sheet, so that the user won't get annoyed if he happen to grab it while using.

I tried locking cells, sheet, but nothing seems to work.

I am using Excel 2007.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really a programming question but the way to do this is...

Right click the image and choose `Size and Properties`.
Click `Properties` tab and under properties,(optional- choose `Don't move or size with cells`) and ensure the `Locked` box is checked.

Highlight the cells of the worksheet you want the users to be able to edit, right click inside one of them and choose `Format Cells`.  In the protection tab uncheck the `locked` checkbox.

Then you can protect the worksheet.  Click `Home`, then `Format`, then `Protect Sheet`.
Make sure you unselect `Select locked cells`, leave the top checkbox selected (`Protect worksheet and contents of locked cells`) as well as `select unlocked cells` checked.